# Where Clause That Grabs Values From A Table And If It Returns Null It Grabs Only Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax, null

What I am trying to do can be exemplified (Incorrectly) by the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE User IN 
    (CASE (SELECT Username From Table2 Where Table2.ID = 1) 
           WHEN IS NULL THEN NULL
           ELSE (SELECT Username From Table2 Where Table2.ID = 1)  END)
```

Since `User = NULL` is not the same as `User IS NULL`  something with the above syntax won't work. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to grab `NULLS` if there are records in Table2.

For Example,

Table1

```
  ID    User
  1     Elias
  2     NULL
```

Table2

```
 ID    Username
 1     Elias
 2     NULL
```

I would want the above select to return the following recordset

```
 ID     User
 1      Elias
```

If I was looking for ID 2 in Table 2 I would want the following recordset

```
ID      User
2       NULL
```

Comment: Please describe what you really want to do.  If your English isn't good (and even if it is!), sample data and desired results are really useful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was in a bit of a rush to post the question. I added columns and (hopefully) added a more comprehensive title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to consider two `NULL` values as matching, you can do:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.user = t2.username or t1.user is null and t2.user is null
             );
```

If you are trying to match values in `table2` and if there are no values in `table2` then return values equal to `NULL` (how I interpret the title):

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.user = t2.username or t1.user is null and t2.user is null
             ) or
      (not exists (select 1 from table2) and t1.user is null);
```

EDIT:

For performance, you can do:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.user = t2.username
             ) or
      exists (select 1 
              from table2
              where t1.user is null and t2.user is null
             ) or
      (not exists (select 1 from table2) and t1.user is null);
```

These can take advantage of an index on `table2(user)`.

Comment: Your second query guided me in the right direction. The only piece it was missing was the `WHERE` clause, which I changed to `ID = 1` after you wrote it. If you incorporate that into your answer I believe that it will help others in the future.

Comment: Also, on a side not, this can cause a small query to get really expensive, really fast. Though I don't know if there is a faster way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A link where you use null as a relation between table will get you a wrong number of rows. Duplicated rows and stuff.

The simplest query I can think of (in order to avoid this) is:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
  on t1.user = t2.username
```

This will filter out the nulls.

In case that you also need to aggregate here null use Gordon's query, though if you have multiple nulls in one of the tables then your query is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use `IN clause`

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE User IN 
(SELECT isnull(Username,'')  From Table2 Where 1 = 1)
```